# Setting up Amazon Simple Queue Service (Amazon SQS)

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs

I have 2 EC2 instances - one master and one worker.
Master instance creates a job and pushes it to SQS and the worker thread listens to it.

My issue is, I need the worker to be able to tell the master that the job was completed. I have been researching about it a bit and the only option that I was able to find was to create 2 SQS threads and use one for sending the jobs to the worker and the other one to send the completed status from the worker to the master.

Is there any other way? I would be OK to use something other than SQS as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of different ways that you could do it (rows in a database for example), but since you are already using SQS, adding another SQS queue to send messages back to the master instance is perfectly acceptable solution in my opinion.

Comment: Oh ok, I was not sure whether it is an "good" solution... anyways, I think I'll stick with 2 SQS threads then. Thanks!